# Are there any ways to search for recursive code in VS or Rider

Tags: visual-studio, rider

I have a very large code base and I am seeing Stack overflow exception without any stack trace in the memory dump of the process. I want to find all the recursive code in the codebase.
Is there any way to achieve in either Visual Studio or Rider or any other way?

Comment: Did you try to debug application step-by-step in your IDE?

Comment: It is not possibe, it is like finding needle in haystack since we do not know where the resursive function/s is

Answer (score 1):

You could use an external tool like https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/ or https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/.

Those tools will allow you to run the code with a profiler running that will easily show you where your memory and time consumed is being spent (they also offer free trial)